# connecting grease pencil drawing to object with armature for animation

Tags: mesh, armature, grease-pencil

For a project, I am creating an animation. For this animation, I need to be able to connect my grease pencil drawing to my object to then be able to animate both.. with grease pencil I clicked on the "surface" option to draw on my surface, but it did not truly connect to the surface..
[image]

[image]

If it is not possible to connect the two, is there any other way to give that scribbling pencil effect to my object?

thank you.

Comment: first how were you planing on rendering the grease pencil? Other ways: UV unwrap your guy and scribble all over a texture.

Comment: Generally you can [parent GP strokes to bone armature](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.78/GPencil#Layer_panel) but there appears to be the control over the movement when strokes are parented to one bone so looks like you need to have as many stroke layers as there are bones.

Answer (score 0):

You can parent the grease pencil marks to the object first select the mark in object mode then the object. It's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>–<kbd>P</kbd> to parent it to the object.

Comment: sorry it's actually control p

Comment: You can always [edit] your posts. Much better to edit, then add corrections in the comments.